# How to Retrieve Large URL Json Data Set?

Tags: json, socrata, soda

I am trying to obtain a data set via json and url, using SODA's API.  The issue is that the data set is greater then 50K, and I need to sort the data set using multiple keys.  Sorting by multiple keys is not something that is permitted by SODA's API.  The question is how could I get around that?

Example (This table is small, but for illustrative purposes I have included it): 
https://data.medicare.gov/resource/apyc-v239.json?$Limit=1000&$Order=measure_id

but once I attempt to add state to the order the API errors out.

The data set above is only 3800 recs, however there are other datasets with over 250000 recs, which require the same approach - sorting, then paging through the results...

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the new API endpoint for that dataset: http://dev.socrata.com/foundry/#/data.medicare.gov/apyc-v239

It'll allow you to sort by multiple columns and there's no maximum for `$limit` on the new endpoints, so you can do stuff like this:

```
https://data.medicare.gov/resource/q7p2-jxeh.json?$order=state,measure_name&$limit=100000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Would anyone happen to know if the new link provides historical data (prior to Jan. 1, 2013) or just current Hospital Compare data.

Comment: The new API endpoint is the exact same data, just faster and with more queryability